# VBA Excel: change Page Break according to number of rows and last row position

Tags: excel, vba, break

I made a workbook consist of few sheets. By using VBA I read varying number of rows on sheet1 and copy them to last sheet that act like some kind of custom report. In most cases this last sheet is long just one page during printing, but sometime VBA routine copy rows with plenty data, arranged into two or more lines of text, so last rows of such reports (where shall be a sign, date, place etc.) appears unexpected on Page 2! And if I made Page break on the way that only Page 1 is printable then my report lost these details; in second case, if I set Page break to 2 pages (and on the page are just few rows of data), then process of printing will produce printing of 2 pages: one filled with data and second, empty!
Is there some way to detect where is situated last row with data, and then from VBA change printing area according to result of detection, to print only Page 1 or Page 1 and Page 2 together!? I tried it by using row number, but some rows have twice height than others, so I gave up!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In meantime, I thought I found simple and working solution (Excel 2010):

```
LastRow3 = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
MsgBox "Last row filled with data is " & LastRow3" 
'detect how many pages is in this sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
tnp= (ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1) * (ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1)
pagnr = "Total number of pages is:" & tnp
MsgBox pagnr
```

After that, based on tnp variable value is probably easy to set Page break with:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$E$80"  ' takes in account Page1 and Page2
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$E$50" 'only one page is for printing
```

Anybody has better solution!? Thank you.

Comment: I simply can't presume how long would be Sheet and to set PageBreak by using VBA code. It would be easy when all rows have same height, but if some of them have different, then I can't calculate will row 50 be in Page1 or Page2,,, tried all things but can't get good solution. Please help.